# Magento website page print issue

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a website which is developed using Magento. everything is working perfect but when i try to print any page of the site to press (ctrl + p), the whole page layout is damaged and also shows the links on print preview page, can anyone help me out that how to print the page as it displays on browser.

This is the link of website : http://www.museluxe.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, you have `/* Todo: Make this happen. */` in your print.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Browser might be performing some cleanup work on it's own. However it appears to miss useful content whatsoever. You can create CSS rule which tells how to render website for printers:

```
@media print {
   ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can include CSS file with `media="print"`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".../print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: From your own site: https://www.museluxe.com/skin/frontend/polar/default/css/print.css